# Problema con Subconsulta SQL

Tags: sql

**BASE DE DATOS Nortwhind** [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Necesito saber los nombres de los clientes que han comprado el producto 'Chai'
el siguiente es el código que he usado para resolver el problema

```
select CompanyName from Customers where CustomerID in
(select CustomerID from Orders where CustomerID in
(select OrderID from [Order Details] where ProductID =
(select ProductID from Products where ProductName='Chai')))
```

El error es el siguiente::

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 Conversion failed when converting
>   the nvarchar value 'ALFKI' to data type int.

Comment: necesitaríamos saber los tipos de datos de las columnas `CustomerID`, `OrderID` y `ProductID`

Comment: A menos que tengas un mal diseño de base de datos, me parece que tienes un error tipografico `... where CustomerID in
(select OrderID ...`, entiendo que debiera ser en todo caso algo así: `... where OrderID in
(select OrderID ...`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes son una serie de tablas enlazadas, es decir que cada una debe tener una clave primaria (única) y una clave foránea que la relaciona con otra de las tablas. Para obtener datos de estas tablas es necesario indicar en la consulta su relación (`JOIN`).

```
select CompanyName from Customers
inner join Orders on Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
inner join [Order Details] on Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID
inner join Products on [Order Details].ProductoID = Products.ProductoID
where ProductName='Chai'
```